# How to select the last element inside a div

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble setting my css with the image inside my div.

I have

```
<div class='test'>

   <a href='#'>   <img src='haha.jpg'/>   </a>
   <a href='#'>   <img src='imageINeed.jpg'/>  </a>

</div>

<div class='test'>

   <a href='#'>   <img src='haha.jpg'/>   </a>
   <a href='#'>   <img src='imageINeed1.jpg'/>  </a>

</div>

<div class='test'>

   <a href='#'>   <img src='haha.jpg'/>   </a>
   <a href='#'>   <img src='imageINeed2.jpg'/>  </a>

</div>
```

My jquery below will select the second image

```
imageSize could be varies.

  $('.test).each(function(){

        $(this).find('img:eq(1)').width(imageSize);
  })
```

However, there are times that I only have 1 `<a>` tag inside the `test` div.

```
    <div class='test'>
       <a href='#'>   <img src='imageINeed2.jpg'/>  </a>
   </div>
```

`eq(1)` won't select the `img` if I only have 1 `<a>` tag

I have tried

```
$('.test).each(function(){
    $(this).find('img:nth-last-child').width(imageSize);
})
```

It won't do it. Are there anyways to do it? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selector:

```
$(".test").find("img:last").width(imageSize);
```

Comment: I have tried it too. but it doesn't work for some reason. It only works with eq(1).